# Calculate RTP jitter for Video

Tags: python, rtsp, rtp

**Hey Guys**

I have an RTP client and want to calculate the jitter based on a timestamp from the RTP header in python.

Maybe someone gives me a hint.

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here https://github.com/alpartis/rtp.jitter/blob/master/rtp_jitter.cpp is a `C++` implementation of the `rtpjitter`, the formulae for calculating it is in `C++` but you can peek it in `_calc_jitter` function at line 393. You can try to implement in in `python`, judging the fact you are implementing a jitter buffer, I can assume you can read a bit of that `C++` implementation.

Comment: Glad to hear and good luck.